# how to use ldap 'Security Group' for httpd hosted Nagios wesite's authentication?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, active-directory, authentication, ldap

**Here is what we are trying to achive:**

We want to authenticate windows active directory users who are part of perticular "Security Group", for NagiOS.

**I've created below new configuration file, for this perpose, as below:**

> **/etc/httpd/conf.d/nagios.conf**
>
> ```
> ScriptAlias /nagios/cgi-bin/ "/usr/lib64/nagios/cgi-bin/"
>
> <Directory "/usr/lib64/nagios/cgi-bin/">
>    Options ExecCGI
>    AllowOverride None
>    Order allow,deny
>    Allow from all
>    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
>    AuthType Basic
>    AuthBasicProvider ldap file
>    AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
>    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server01.mytestdomain.com:389/CN=Nagios_Auth_Group,OU=Test,OU=IT,OU=authorization,DC=mytestdomain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?"
>    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Nagios_User,OU=Users,DC=mytestdomain,DC=local"
>    AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypass#01"
>    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute  memberUid
>    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
>    Require ldap-group "CN=Nagios_Auth_Group,OU=Test,OU=IT,OU=authorization,DC=mytestdomain,DC=local"
>    AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
>    Require valid-user
> </Directory> 
>
> Alias /nagios "/usr/share/nagios/html"
>
> <Directory "/usr/share/nagios/html">
>    Options None
>    AllowOverride None
>    Order allow,deny
>    Allow from all
>    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
>    AuthType Basic
>    AuthBasicProvider ldap file
>    AuthName "LDAP Authentication"
>    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://server01.mytestdomain.com:389/CN=Nagios_Auth_Group,OU=Test,OU=IT,OU=authorization,DC=mytestdomain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?"
>    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Nagios_User,OU=Users,DC=mytestdomain,DC=local"
>    AuthLDAPBindPassword "mypass#01"
>    AuthLDAPGroupAttribute  memberUid
>    AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on
>    Require ldap-group "CN=Nagios_Auth_Group,OU=Test,OU=IT,OU=authorization,DC=mytestdomain,DC=local"
>    AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users
>    Require valid-user
> </Directory>
> ```

**Error received:**

> **/var/log/httpd/error_log**
>
> ```
> [Date and Time removed] [auth_basic:error] [pid XXXXXX] [client 127.0.0.1:44068] AH01617: user nagios_test_user01: authentication failure for "/nagios/": Password Mismatch
> ```

**Additional Info which might be useful to help resolve the error or configuration issue:**

> **OS Details:**
>
> ```
> NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
> VERSION="7.3 (Maipo)"
> ID="rhel"
> ID_LIKE="fedora"
> VERSION_ID="7.3"
> PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
> ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
> CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.3:GA:server"
> HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
> BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
>
> REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
> REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.3
> REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
> REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.3"
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
> Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
> ```
>
> **uname -a**
>
> ```
> Linux server07 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP [Date & Time details removed] x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> ```
>
> **httpd -v**
>
> ```
> Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat Enterprise Linux)
> Server built:   [Date & Time details removed]
> ```
>
> **Nagios Version**
>
> ```
> Nagios® Core™ Version 4.2.4
> ```
>
> **Error**
>
> ```
> [Mon Mar 02 09:33:12.273726 2020] [auth_basic:error] [pid 38654] [client 127.0.0.1:57388] AH08217: user test_user: authentication failure for "/nagios/": Password Mismatch
> ```

Comment: Wait, why are you specifying a group as BindDN?

Comment: @user1686: that’s how I understood the man page ... but I could be wrong... if I’m please let me know what I need to put it there?

Comment: In that case where does the bind password `mypass#01` come from? As far as I know, groups don't have passwords...

Comment: @user1686: that's correct we also have a service account in AD with the name "Nagios_User" & that password is of that service account & not of the "Nagios_Auth_Group" group.

Comment: But your config never told Apache to _use_ that service account.

Comment: Better to start using port `636` or `3269` for LDAP over SSL or LDAPS if you can. I noticed you were using `389`. If you can authenticate, I don't believe you have to import CA cert either but only 75% sure atm. In any case, did you also see .... [`Fixed, instructions say use htpasswd.users, however in /etc/httpd/conf.d it looks for /etc/nagios/passwd.`](https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?225970-nagios-401-will-not-accept-username-password-SOLVED)... That said, perhaps you simple need to comment out `##AuthUserFile /etc/nagios/htpasswd.users` since you're authenticating via LDAP.

Comment: Furthermore, ensure you are using `AuthBasicProvider ldap`, `AuthLDAPGroupAttributeIsDN on`, and `AuthLDAPGroupAttribute member`... do your homework on those and ensure you know what the `file` is in the way your config shows it as `AuthBasicProvider ldap file`.... I think you just have a trivial problem here with the configuration options you need for how you are authenticating and such to LDAP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're specifying the wrong DN in `AuthLDAPBindDN`. The "Bind" parameters allow Apache *itself* to log in to the LDAP server before performing lookups – so it does not make sense to specify a group here, it must be a valid user account.

In this case, because you've specified a `BindPW` that belongs to the "Nagios_User" account, then `BindDN` must of course specify the *name* of that account:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=Nagios_User,OU=Services,DC=mytestdomain,DC=local"
AuthLDAPBindPW "mypass#01"
```

For convenience, Active Directory also accepts non-standard shorthand form:

```
AuthLDAPBindDN "Nagios_User@mytestdomain.local"
```

Comment: Thanks Pal. However I have few more queries on it,  where do I mention "Nagios_Auth_Group" Group and how do I make sure only users of that security group are allowed to access it? and where do I point the AuthLDAPURL, if my users could be in any OU's in the root of the domain?

Comment: I've tried your solution but I'm getting an error. I updated details of configuration and error in the question. please check and let me know what's going wrong.

Comment: @Hrish - `AuthLDAPURL` can be set to the domain root to search the whole domain - you can verify with the `ldapsearch` command. `Require ldap-group` is the one that determines a user needs to be in the group.

Comment: @user19702 yes it’s able to find the user as far as I understand but the error it shows as Auth failure now... please check the error I updated in the end of the question description.